# Continuous Integration With VSTS and AWS EC2 Instances

Tags: amazon-ec2, azure-devops, devops, continuous-deployment, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

We are managing source code in the VSTS there we had the Main Git Branch. And now we want to automate the deployment/release process with AWS EC2 instance.

We installed the AWS Toolkit for Visual Studio 2017 from the marketplace.

Can anyone guide how to deploy to AWS EC2 instance from VSTS?

Answer (score 0):

You are talking about IaaS (Infrastructure as a code) there are several ways which you can able to achieve this.

Tools like terraform, ansible, cloud formation we're some popular tools which you can able to create an Ec2 instance from VSTS or Azure DevOps.

For an instance you can see [here](https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-ec2-instance/blob/master/examples/basic/main.tf) on how you can create an ec2 instance using terraform.

You can install the [terraform extension from market place](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mauve.terraform) into your azure devops account.